# sitting position... sitting on hams

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, image-identification

Does the following sentence best present the sitting position shown in the picture?

---

He is sitting kneeled down.

---

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could say:

> He is sitting on his heels.

or

> He is knelt back on his heels.
>   He is kneeling back on his heels.

Comment: There are a number of yoga guides that describe it similarly to “Kneel on your mat, big toes touching, and sit on your heels.” The kneeling and sitting on your heels are treated somewhat separately even though kneeling is the easiest way to sit on your heels...

Answer (score 0):

I would say

> He sits in a kneeling position.
>
> He is in a kneeling position.

Your sentence seems grammatically correct to me.

Comment: "seems grammatically correct" or "seems grammatically incorrect?"

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo "seems grammatically correct" or "I can't see what is wrong with it"

Comment: To be *knelt down* (**knelt** is the usual pp form of the verb **kneel**) means to be on one or both knees in a kneeling position, which implies a roughly 90-degree angle at the knee joint(s).  The spine can be arched forward: *The EMT was knelt down over the injured person, administering first aid*.   So we cannot be ***sitting** knelt (or kneeled) down*.